# QBO API - Query Purchases for a given customer

Tags: quickbooks-online

I am trying to get a list of all transactions specifically purchases that are tied to a customer in quickbooks online via their REST API. From what I can tell this doesn't seem possible which I find hard to believe.

This seems like a very basic requirement.

I have tried things like:

```sql
select * from purchase where EntityRef.value='100'

select * from purchase where CustomerRef.value='100'
```

**EDIT**
When I query where EntityRef='100' I get the following

```
{
 "Message": "Invalid query",
 "Detail": "QueryValidationError: property 'EntityRef' is not queryable",
 "code": "4001"
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it is possible. What kind of queries did you try already?

Answer (score 1):

From what I have found, `EntityRef` is not a filterable attribute, therefore is not allowed to run a SQL query through their API.

Comment: I have not found any solution to this

Answer (score -1):

As stated in [QuickBooks API documentation about Purchases](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/purchase) there is a special queryable field for that:

**EntityRef**: Specifies the party with whom an expense is associated. Can be `Customer`, `Vendor`, or `Employee`.

Query the corresponding name list resource of the associated type to determine the appropriate object for this reference. Use the `Id` and `DisplayName` values from that object for `EntityRef.value` and `EntityRef.name`, respectively. Set `EntityRef.type` to the type of object associated with this expense.

For example, if this object represents a purchase from a vendor, then set `EntityRef.type` to `Vendor` and query the Vendor resource for the appropriate object to reference.

Comment: When I try select * from Purchase where EntityRef.value='100' I get an error that there is no property of EntityRef.value for a purchase

Comment: Wouldn't that contain the vendor that the purchase was made from? Bills and purchases can be associated with a vendor who your buying from, and then the lines can be tied to a customer. I need any bills/purchases which have lines associated with a specific customer.

Comment: @JoshBerke can you provide exact errors you see?

Comment: And try to use `select * from purchase where EntityRef='100'` or  `select * from purchase where EntityRefValue='100'`